# What is an elegant way to accomplish: explode -> apply some_func -> implode without a foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, coding-style

I have a string of delimiter-separated values, and need to perform some_func on each of the values in the string. What is the most compact/elegant way to accomplish this? Here is the code I would currently use:

```
$delim = ',';
$source_array = explode($delim, $source_string);

$destination_array = array();
foreach ($source_array as $val) {
    $destination_array[] = some_function($val);
}
$destination_string = implode($delim, $destination_array);
```

Ordering is not important, but would be nice to preserve.

Thanks!

Comment: Why did people downvote this?

Comment: Because he is trying to learn, that's bad you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$delim = ',';
$source_array = explode($delim, $source_string);
$destination_array = array_map('some_function', source_array)
$destination_string = implode($delim, $destination_array);
```

Comment: Or on one line: `$dest = implode(",",array_map("some_function",explode(",",$source)));`

Comment: Thanks! It seems like there isn't a shortcut function for avoiding a sequence of explode-then-implode? ... I should have known to use array_map -- appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expressions/ REGEX. Or if the algorithm is heavy make a script in Perl to handle all this and call it from PHP. It will make things easier.

Well, i know, someone will tell you Python or another scripting language, but thats my 2 cents.

Comment: -1 Recommending a sledghammer approach of regexp or an alternative programming language, when the OPs own choice of language provides a solution to his problem isn't really a very good answer.

Comment: Now i have to go and watch sledgehammer,

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).
This way you can apply a function to each entry in the array. So your code would look like this:

```
$delim = ',';
$parts = explode($delim, $source_string);
array_walk($parts, 'some_function');
$destination_string = implode($delim, $parts);
```

Compared to `array_map`, it won't generate a new array but work on the existing array... but that's only going to be significant if you work with huge arrays (think memory). And of course it won't work if you have to access other array values in `some_function`...